# Is WebGL hardware accelerated on mobile platforms?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, webgl

I'm surprised how much trouble I'm having finding an answer to this question.  I want to know if WebGL is hardware accelerated on iOS and android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on the phones it's available on it is hardware accelerated. For iOS that's iOS8 and newer. For Android it depends on the device. If WebGL is supported on that device it's hardware accelerated.

That said, most mobile GPUs have far less power than desktop GPUs so while lots of WebGL content will run, some of it will run much slower. It depends on the particular WebGL program and the GPU.

Comment: Is there a way to find out for sure if your device supports it?

Comment: If a device supports WebGL it's almost 100% sure it's GPU based. I know of no software based WebGL on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile platforms that support WebGL, it would be a very safe bet that it is being processed by the GPU. Both Android and iOS support OpenGL ES 2.0 for quite some time now which is what WebGL is built around and is used extensively to accelerate the user interface.